# I didn't not find leaks on my UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, memory-leaks

I think I have some leaks caused from my UIImage. In fact, there are lots of images that are downloaded and I think that when I download the new picture, it's showed upper the older and the older aren't dealloc or released...

```
// Create and posit the UIImage
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
NSLog(@"retain count 1 : %i", [imageView retainCount]);
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
NSLog(@"retain count 2 : %i", [imageView retainCount]);
//[imageView setImage:image];
//[imageView initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,64,320,367);
NSLog(@"retain count 3 : %i", [imageView retainCount]);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
NSLog(@"retain count 4 : %i", [imageView retainCount]);
[imageView release];
NSLog(@"retain count 5 : %i", [imageView retainCount]);
NSLog(@"-----------------------");
```

That code give me that result :

```
retain count 1 : 0
retain count 2 : 0
retain count 3 : 1
retain count 4 : 1
retain count 5 : 2
retain count 6 : 1
-----------------------
retain count 1 : 0
retain count 2 : 0
retain count 3 : 1
retain count 4 : 1
retain count 5 : 2
retain count 6 : 1
-----------------------
retain count 1 : 0
retain count 2 : 0
retain count 3 : 1
retain count 4 : 1
retain count 5 : 2
retain count 6 : 1
-----------------------
```

Apparently, The image were released and there is only 1, but the older still on the phone's screen.. apparently...

If there are more pictures on the screen, how can I release the older pictures???

Thanks to read my questions!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,64,320,367);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
}
```

you should `release` the allocated `imageView`

Answer (score 0):

You are **alloc**  **imageView** and not release it.

So release it after add to view.

```
[imageView release];
```

Comment: Bhalara  if release the ImageView after view.addSubView:imageView, the result looks like before, lots of image are shown

Comment: Then better is make imageView as a global and then just change image.

Comment: @Cheltan Bhalara : OK, I did it but [imageView setImage:image] or [imageView initWithImage:image] doesn't replace correctly the line imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; ...

Answer (score 0):

rather than creating a new imageView everytime your connection finishes, you should just set the image property of the imageView

Comment: thanks for your help! So I can put the UIImageView as a proprety, and how can I change this line : UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; ??

Comment: you make UIImageView *imageView property of your class. Then you can just code: self.imageView.image = image;

Comment: Ok thanks, I made that but there is no image shown.. I use self.imageView.image = image; and before I used imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

Comment: did you make sure its the same imageView that you create and set as subview?